# Find the original MeasureBase value with python-measurement

Tags: python, units-of-measurement, measurement

`python-measurement` is a library to read measurements pythonically, https://python-measurement.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html e.g.

```
>>> from measurement.measures import Weight
>>> w = Weight(lb=135) # Represents 135lbs
>>> print w
135.0 lb
>>> print w.kg
61.234919999999995
```

When I read the measurement object directly into django/ORM/DB, I'm not sure why it automatically converted to the `default_unit`, e.g.

- When reading `1 us_qt`, it returns a a `MeasureBase` object with the value `.001 cubic_meter`

In the database, the value is `.001` and the unit is `cubic_meter`, but I need to see what the original unit was - ie `US qt`.

**Is there a way to see the original unit (at a minimum, as the value can be computed) and value that was entered?**

Comment: You might have to use the guess function first before converting.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably, there's some mechanism in your Django/DB library that uses `python-measurement` defaults the different subclasses of `MeasureBase` to some default units. Like how the "standard unit" feature is used in the [doc example](https://python-measurement.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/creating_your_own_class.html#using-formula-based-conversions).

```
from sympy import S, Symbol
from measurement.base import MeasureBase

class Temperature(MeasureBase):
    SU = Symbol('kelvin')
    STANDARD_UNIT = 'k'
    UNITS = {
        'c': SU - S(273.15),
        'f': (SU - S(273.15)) * S('9/5') + 32,
        'k': 1.0
    }
    ALIAS = {
        'celsius': 'c',
        'fahrenheit': 'f',
        'kelvin': 'k',
    }
```

What you can try then is to guess the units independently using the native `python-measurement` functions, e.g.

```
>>> from measurement.utils import guess
>>> m = guess(10, 'qt')
>>> repr(m)
Volume(qt=10.0)
```